# Flutter Flatbutton onpressend not working

Tags: flutter

I have a register page in which there are 3 input fields and on next button i need to change the input field and show the other so i have simply use boolean to show/hide input. But when i click on button its not changing the fields (Mean change the boolean to false/true) And even i try to simply add print so i can check but its not even printing the value. But if i use navigator to change page its working fine in button.

My code

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  bool  first = true;
  bool  second = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "SIGNUP",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/icons/signup.svg",
              height: size.height * 0.35,
            ),
            first ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Name",
              icon: Icons.person,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ) : Container(),
            first ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Email",
              icon: Icons.mail,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ) : Container() ,

            first ? RoundedPasswordField(
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ) : Container() ,

            second ? RoundedInputField(
              hintText: "Your Number",
              icon: Icons.phone,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print(value);
              },
            ) : Container() ,
            first ? Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              width: size.width * 0.8,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
                child: FlatButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                  onPressed: (){
                    print('working');
                    setState(){
                      first = false;
                      second = true;
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'NEXT',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ): Container(),

            second ? RoundedButton(
              text: "REGISTER",
              press: () {
                print('working');
              },
            ) : Container() ,
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.03),
            AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
              login: false,
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return LoginScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i am using setState to change the boolean value which isn't working also try to simply print the string but its also not working. If i use navigator in this to change page its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should declare `first` and `second` at instance level, otherwise they will created again with default values after `setState`is executed.

   ```
    class Body extends StatelessWidget {
        bool first = true;
        bool second = false;

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ....
        }
    }
   ```
2. `setState` is used incorrectly. You need to have

   ```
   setState((){
       first = false;
       second = true;
   });
   ```

   Your code is calling `setState` without any action and **after** that, you change `first` and `second` variables (but outside `setState`).

   Your code is equivalent to

   ```
   setState();
   first = false;
   second = true;
   ```
3. You should not declare again `first` and `second` inside `onPressed`, otherwise you'll be dealing with new variables which only scope is this method

   ```
   setState((){
       first = false;
       second = true;
   });
   ```
4. Your widget needs to be stateful and not stateless, otherwise it can't change the state.

Comment: I try to declate it at the instance level but still its not changing also its not printing value i think maybe its cause due to statelessWidget ? I need to use StatefullWidget ?

Comment: Yes, missed that your widget was stateless.. updated my answer.